# How do you permanently remove websites from the address bar?

Tags: google-chrome, address-bar

I want to delete some urls from the address bar autocomplete suggestions, but is won't work, no matter what I do. Shift+Backspace doesn't work, and when it does, it's only temporary. What do I do?

Comment: You can clear Chrome browsing History (All Time) but it will just build up again.   So permanently stop it?  No, I do not think so.

Comment: I at least want to remove all for now, so that it won't come up. I can't clear my history either, (admin restrictions) so I need a different solution

Answer (score 1):

Start typing the URL in the address bar and make sure it is highlighted.  Then on a Windows computer use shift + delete.  This will delete the URL from your autocomplete history.  If you have a Mac, use fn + shift + delete.  I hope this helps.  Also, I downloaded Chrome, put in several URLs and made sure they populated when I started typing one of them in the address bar. I then went to another tab, and started typing in one of the URLs and as it started populating, the URL was highlighted. I then (I have a mac) pressed my fn then shift then delete (hold down fn, shift and then delete) and part of the URL went away. I closed chrome and reopened. I then started typing in the same URL and the URL did not pre-populate as before.  –

Comment: This doesn't work either, shift backspace or shift delete doesn't work.

Comment: Ok, One moment and I will post a different solution.

Comment: Richard,  I downloaded Chrome, put in several URLs and made sure they populated when I started typing one of them in the address bar.  I then went to another tab, and started typing in one of the URLs and as it started populating, the URL was highlighted.  I then (I have a mac) pressed my fn then shift then delete and part of the URL went away.  I closed chrome and reopened.  I then started typing in the same URL and the URL did not pre-populate as before.  Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes, I don't know what is going on, but again, whenever I try and it somehow works, a few minutes later, its back. I can't clear my history, so if that's the problem, then I'm out of luck. Hopefully there is another way because it is extremely irritating.